# Autoconf: detecting if target platform is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: autoconf

In GNU Autoconf: is there an easy way (premade macro? or autoconf-archive macro?) to determine the bitness of our target platform is 32-bit or 64-bit? In case you are curious why I asked this: I need to know this since in the good'old Fortran (pre-2003) there is no way to determine if size_t is 4-byte or 8-byte wide.

Answer (score 5):

You can use AC_CHECK_SIZEOF to determine the size of a void *.  ( I assume the definition of "64 bit" machine is that void * are size 8, although perhaps you care about the size of an int.)

Comment: Well if it's about `size_t`, `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([size_t])` is what should be placed into `configure.ac`.